# How to break recursive error when updating PIP

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to update PIP (the Python package installer) so I can install a package in Python, but in order to do so, I need to use a PIP command. Essentially, I can't update PIP without having PIP been updated (i.e the command is python -m pip install --upgrade pip).

The error message is get is:
`You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.`
`You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

In addition, the packages that I am attempting to install do not install.

I'm unsure how to get around this problem, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. If you want to get rid of it, just run the command it tells you to. If you get an actual error, please provide it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it with administration privileges.

```sh
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

*** If you are using windows run the command prompt as the administration